# Print session attributes in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

My webapp is ready but I just wanted to add a little dropdown menu with the username as title. This is my jsp code:

```
                <i class="icon-user"></i> 
                <%
                    session.getAttribute("name");
                %>
                <span class="caret"></span>
```

and it sais

session cannot be resolved

```
9:              <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
10:                     <i class="icon-user"></i> 
11:                     <%
12:                         session.getAttribute("name");
13:                     %>
14:                     <span class="caret"></span>
15:                 </a>
```

There is a session because I'm logged in.

Kind regards,

Comment: What frameoworks are you using?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use EL, which is prefered in JSP.

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.name}"/>
```

Or if the `name` value is HTML safe, you can use

```
${sessionScope.name}
```

Make sure the JSP is allow access session.

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
```

To use core JSTL, make sure the following code is included.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: @Pau what do you mean by `name` value is HTML safe?

Answer (score 10):

You can try an alternative:

```
<% request.getSession().getAttribute("name") %>
```

The reason that `session` is not getting resolved is because you must have set `session="false"` in your page directive.

[Read this for further reference](http://www.coderanch.com/t/560090/JSP/java/unable-access-implicit-object-session).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with answer given by @Pau Kiat Wee. But you can also set this user name from the controller in modelmap and then just simple use it in a EL. That would also be a good option. Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In your servlet:

```
 1) get your parameter:

    String param = request.getParameter("param");

 2) send it to the request object as an attribute:

    request.setAttribute("param", param);
```

In your JSP:

```
   use JSTL, and EL to return the attribute you sent from your servlet:

   <input type="text" name="param" value="<c:out value="${param}" />" />
```

and there you go.