# Spring HTTP Session Issue - Getting Null attribute values

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, session, servlets

I am trying to set the value of my session in my Controller class and get the session attribute value in my JSP. I seem to have done everything but I get only null when i try to print the session value.
Please help me. I am new to Spring
Please find my codebase below

OffersController.java

```
package com.sharat.spring.web.mvc;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class OffersController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(HttpSession session){

        session.setAttribute("name", "Sharat");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

offers-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sharat.spring.web.mvc"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>55SpringSettingSessionAttribute</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Second Attempt</title>
</head>
<body>
Fresh !! Please work for me
<p/>
<%= session.getAttribute("name") %>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know why I do not get any value for my session attributes. Please help with pointers.

Thanks in advance.
Sharat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to access the session in the wrong way from the jsp. Try to take a look to this thread: [Print session attributes in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993429/print-session-attributes-in-jsp)