# Get Radio button value in another jsp without using forms

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a radio button and href link in 1st jsp, whenever click the href the 2nd jsp will open. My question is that how can I get the selected radio button value in 2nd jsp page.

```html
jsp1: 

<table>
<tr> 
  <td>Environment</td> 
  <td align="left" class="td"><input type="radio" name="env"  value="xx" checked/>xx 
  <input type="radio" name="env" value="yy"/>yy</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td class="td" colspan="2"><a class="all"    href="abc.htm">click here</a>
  </td>   
</tr>
</table>
```

```html
jsp 2:

selected input is : ${env}
```

Thanks in advance,
arul

Comment: Please elaborate. Post samples of jsp1 and jsp2 and any other helpful piece of code. See [ask]

Comment: Write a javascript function that reads the value on page one and use Ajax to send to another page. Bind this javascript function with onClick event on the link in page one.

Comment: Welcome to SO, have you tried setting button value in request parameter for JSP2 to read?

Comment: @Sagar Rohankar. I tried to set the value in session object, but i didn't know how can to get the selected button value in same jsp page.

Comment: jsp1: '<tr>
    <td>Environment</td>
    <td align="left" class="td"><input type="radio" name="env" value="xx" checked/>xx 
    <input type="radio" name="env" value="yy"/>yy</td>
   </tr>'

<tr> 
    <td class="td" colspan="2"><a class="all" href="abc.htm">click here</a></td>
   </tr>

jsp 2:

selected input is: ${env}

Comment: @arulmurugan Please move you source code from the comment section to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use javascript to submit that value to second JSP (You can simply search how to submit form using javascript and you will get your answer, I suggest use POST method to submit the form)
2. put that button value in session object (directly available in JSP, no import needed) , You can follow this answer for how to use session in JSP :
   [Print session attributes in another JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993429/print-session-attributes-in-jsp)

Be careful with session object, make sure that you initialize that parameter to null to avoid reading the same value again by mistake.