# welcome user small statement for jsp

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

i want to get username from database 
and shows it at jsp 
i have db.java

```
      System.out.println(uname+" "+uemail+" "+upassword);
        Connection conn =  getConnection(); 
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        int upassi=Integer.parseInt(upassword);
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user where uname="+sq+uname+sq+"and uemail="+sq+uemail+sq+"and upassword"+upassword);
        while(result.next()){
            User user = new User(result.getString("uname"),result.getString("uemail"), result.getString("upassword"));    
            System.out.println("Search User from DB"+user);
```

and servlet

```
        if(op.equals("SIGNIN")){
        User user = flowersDB.searchUser(uname , uemail,upassword);
        if(user == null){
            msg = "notfound";
            System.out.println("user="+uemail+"is not found");
            user = new User();

        }        
     else{
         msg = "found";
         System.out.println("user="+uemail+"is found");
     }
```

and welcome page jsp

```
      <h2> welcome </h2><br><br>
```

i want a statament beside welcome that shows the username?how?

Comment: before your servlet redirects to the jsp you need to add the variable to a session or request

Comment: i have add the redirects      ' session.setAttribute("user", user);
         session.setAttribute("msg", msg);
         System.out.println("user="+user);
         url="/index2.jsp";'

Comment: Please edit your question with this information.  **now** in your JSP you need to access this variable - see the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993429/print-session-attributes-in-jsp)