# Model object in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

What is the scope of attributes that we add inside model object? 
For eg: 
Foo foo = new Foo();
model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
Can "foo" be used by multiple requests?

Answer (score 0):

As I know "Model" is Springs interface which is used in Controllers for returning data to the view.
In your JSP your should be able to print your Foo Object by ${foo} because you added it to the models attributes. And it is just for the current request.

Example:
https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-model-interface

If you want something over multiple requests you should maybe use Session Object.
In your Controller you can take HttpServletRequest `request.getSession().addAttribute(foo);`
and print it like described here [Print session attributes in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993429/print-session-attributes-in-jsp).